# Script se "traba" al ejecutar Utilities.formatString('%s', "texto")

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

([Traducción de mi pregunta en SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41625069), sin respuesta hasta el día de la publicación de esta pregunta)

Estimados, hola. Estoy escribiendo una función para usar en una hoja de cálculo de Google, pero esta se traba al tratar de ejecutar `Utilities.formatString()`. Este es el script con el que estoy haciendo pruebas:

```javascript
/*
El argumento 'row' es un array:
["700002", 1234567890, "GROUP", "JOHN Q TAXPAYER", (new Date(1483336800000)), (new Date(-2209075151000)), 3333444455, "SALE", 20, "OK - (111111)", ""]
*/
function formatLog(row) {
  var e1 = row[7];
  var e2 = row[6];
  var e3 = row[8];
  var e4 = row[9];
  var ans = Utilities.formatString("Event %s %s %4.2f %s", e1, e2, e3, e4);  // El código se "traba" aquí
  return ans;
}

function testFormatLog() {
  var input_row = ["700002", 1234567890, "GROUP", "JOHN Q TAXPAYER", (new Date(1483336800000)), (new Date(-2209075151000)), 3333444455, "SALE", 20, "OK - (111111)", ""];
  var text_log = formatLog(input_row);
  Logger.log(text_log);
}
```

Al depurar la función `testFormatLog()`, la transcripción de la ejecución muestra lo siguiente:

> ```
> [17-01-13 10:41:45:399 CST] Iniciando ejecución
> [17-01-13 10:42:04:308 CST] Error de ejecución: 
>                             Lo sentimos, se produjo un error en el servidor. 
>                             Aguarde un momento e inténtelo de nuevo. 
>                             [18.898 segundos de tiempo de ejecución total]
> ```

He intentado incluso ejecutar `Utilites.formatString('%s', "abc")`, ¡y hasta esta línea se traba!

¿Estoy escribiendo mal algo? ¿Alguien ha tenido el mismo problema y sabe cómo solucionarlo?

Comment: @Barranca: ¿Has visto la respuesta que dejé hace unos días? ¿Te sirvió?

Comment: @Rubén Hola. Si, lo intenté, y sin embargo el error persiste. Estoy tratando otras alternativas. También tengo pendiente intentarlo en otra maquina (en caso de que sea algo en mi equipo o en la conexión a Internet que uso)

Comment: Considera agregar más detalles, por ejemplo, el nombre versión del sistema operativo y navegador que estás usando, si has intentado en modo de navegación privada/incógnito con todas las extensiones inhabilitadas, si te conectas desde casa, una red pública o corporativa, etc.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no es posible reproducir el problema.

Answer (score 0):

En relación a que intentaste con `Utilites.formatString('%s', "abc")`, acabo de probar con lo siguiente:

```
function myFunction() {
  var data = Utilities.formatString('%s', 'abc');
  Logger.log(data)
}
```

Funcionó sin problemas. Por esta razón asumo que se trata de un error ajeno a tu código, así que como dice el mensaje,

> ... aguarde un momento e inténtelo de nuevo

Si el problema persiste, intenta con el código que he indicado en esta respuesta.